# How is the process of irui done?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

How is the process of irui done and is it done differently on different materials? If yes, how is it done on each of these materials?

Comment: Welcome to mi yodeya laser!

Comment: This site is meant to accomedate users of many different backgrounds, including those unfamiliar with definitions, and contexts of technicla terms like irruy. Please edit to clarify this.